# sleep in for loop for total iteration time of 2 minutes

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, sleep

I have a for loop inside a while (1) and I want the loop to average approx 2 minutes through each entire for loop cycle.  This requires sleeping between each iteration for a different time based on execution time of the iteration and time remaining in my 2 minute shot clock.  Any ideas.

I was moving towards something

```
while(true)
{
   unsigned long begin_loop = OCX::micro_stamp();
   for (int i = 0; i < _vector.size(); i++) 
    {
        unsigned long start = OCX::micro_stamp();
        unsigned long avg = ( ( begin_loop - start) / ( i + 1 ) );
        usleep ( ( 120000000 - ( (_vector.size() - i) * avg ) ) / ( _vector.size() - i ) );
        try
        {



        }
        catch {
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Create an event object and wait on that towards the end of each loop iteration.

Comment: I plan to sleep at the end of each iteration but need to know the math behind how to calculate the sleep time at the end of each iteration as it will vary.

Comment: The sleep time is going to be something along the lines of `120 - (now - topOfLoopTime).TotalSeconds`.

Comment: that would cause the first iteration to sleep very long and the last to not sleep at all.

Comment: I was moving towards something like above

Comment: I was envisioning `topOfLoopTime` to be taken at the top of the loop body (within the loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of each iteration, sleep for

```
((120000000 - total elapsed microseconds) / (vector.size() - i))
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of each iteration, sleep for ((120 - total elapsed time) / (vector.size() - i))